# Is Windows Forms callback or message based?

Tags: .net, winforms

I tried using google and I couldn't find a short and concrete answer about this. I know that in some frameworks like Qt when a signal is emited it is translated into a callback according to the connected slot (crossing thread boundaries is the exception).

How does Windows Forms work? Is a message or event emited everytime I click a button and then the handler is called when the message is processed in the message loop? Or does it just use a callback mechanism? I.e, if I click a button, the button object just calls the handler.

Comment: Windows sends a message to tell that the button was clicked.  Detected in Control.WndProc(), turned into an event by Control.OnClick().

Comment: Thanks! So how is the event created by Control.OnClick() handled? Assuming an event handler exists, is the event handler through a callback mechanism? Or should it be processed in some event loop?

Comment: Windows Forms is based on Win32, which works the same as any Win32 application.  However, this gets translated into the .NET runtime to get dispatched through the .NET Windows Forms event model.  Read more about how Win32 messaging works here: http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson05.htm

Comment: Is the conclusion that even for the cases that could be solved directly calling the handler, a new event in emited and then caught in the event loop?